# Variance: logical/mathematical meaning

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$$\operatorname {Var} (X)=\operatorname {E} \left[(X-\mu )^{2}\right]$$
Is the formula of variance. But if you think of it, you can assume that square was introduced just that something other than zero could be computed. But is there other mathematical explanation of raising in power? Can it be 3,4 etc instead of square?

Comment: Have a look to the linked question.

Comment: It's because the average, minimize this specific error function. I mean if it was with power 3, than we could find $m$ instead of $\mu$ that would bring it to the minimum.